# The most idiomatic way to perform conditional concatenation of strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm curious what would be the best way to build a String value via sequential appending of text chunks, if some of chunks dynamically depend on external conditions. The solution should be idiomatic for Scala without much speed and memory penalties.

For instance, how one could re-write the following Java method in Scala?

```java
public String test(boolean b) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("a").append(1);
    if (b) {
        s.append("b").append(2);
    }
    s.append("c").append(3);
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: I would say it is pretty idiomatic (and it is easy to follow code flow) for Scala too, except return statement and etc

Comment: I expected something like concatenating lists of Any's with optional components, flattening them and invoking mkString on the result.

Comment: Can anyone suggest something in the following vein: `(Some("a" :: 1 :: Nil) :: (if (b) Some("b" :: 2 :: Nil) else None) :: Some("c" :: 3 :: Nil) :: Nil).flatten.flatten.mkString` but simpler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Scala is both functional and imperative, the term idiomatic depends on which paradigm you prefer to follow. You've solved the problem following the imperative paradigm. Here's one of the ways you could do it functionally:

```
def test( b : Boolean ) =
  "a1" + 
  ( if( b ) "b2" else "" ) +
  "c3"
```

Comment: this also uses a single `StringBuilder` under the hood, so good performance. Actually, bytecode-wise, this is almost identical to your Java code.

Comment: While this will obviously work, it does feel as if you're sacrificing a bit of readability.

Answer (score 9):

These days, idiomatic means string interpolation.

```scala
s"a1${if(b) "b2" else ""}c3"
```

You can even nest the string interpolation:

```scala
s"a1${if(b) s"$someMethod" else ""}"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if b is false, it needs an else or else it prints "()".

Answer (score 5):

What about making the different components of the string functions in their own right? They have to make a decision, which is responsibility enough for a function in my book.

```
def test(flag: Boolean) = {
  def a = "a1"
  def b = if (flag) "b2" else ""
  def c = "c3" 
  a + b + c
}
```

The added advantage of this is it clearly breaks apart the different components of the final string, while giving an overview of how they fit together at a high level, unencumbered by anything else, at the end.

Comment: @collapsar Not sure why you edited the answer to put underscores before the function names - but I've removed them as I can't see any benefit that's worth making the code all ugly. Happy to discuss if you have a reason.

Comment: ah, seen that b was used twice. have just changed the name of the boolean value in preference to using underscores everywhere as I think it leaves the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: why don't you make parts defined as vals?

Comment: No reason, I think because I mainly write in ruby where I'm used to doing this with a class with lots of small methods.

Comment: (I also tend to never use local assignments - it's less functional after all and enforces evaluation you may not need)

Answer (score 2):

As @om-nom-nom said, yours is already sufficiently idiomatic code

```
def test(b: Boolean): String = {
  val sb = new StringBuilder
  sb.append("a").append(1)
  if (b) sb.append("b").append(2)
  sb.append("c").append(3)
  sb.toString
}
```

I can suggest an alternative version, but it's not necessarily more performant or "scala-ish"

```
def test2(b: Boolean): String = "%s%d%s%s%s%d".format(
  "a", 
  1,
  if (b) "b" else "",
  if (b) 2 else "",
  "c",
  3)
```

Comment: Using scalaz: `(Seq("a", 1) ++ b.option("b") ++ b.option(2) ++ Seq("c", 3)).mkString`.

Comment: @senia scalaz is great, but for this particular task it (and some other proposed answers) looks like an over engineering simple idea. I don't think we should complicate things *just because we can*

Comment: @om-nom-nom: In my opinion it seems a little bit better than `if .. else ""`.

Comment: @senia why? I think `if ... else` is easier to parse by most readers, and performance wise constructing multiple options, then constructing sequence from them and so on isn't better performance-wise, finally, you're not using options compasibility to any significant extent. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I think it's the most declarative approach, when there is no useful data in the `else` branch. `if` without `else` is an imperative style. Fast but verbose and with mutable state. `if` with useless empty string is not a declarative way - why should we place `""` into our collection? `if (...) Some(...) else None` is declarative but verbose. `b.option(...)` is shorter version of `if .... else None`.

Answer (score 2):

In scala, a String can be treated as a sequence of characters. Thus, an idiomatic functional way to solve your problem would be with `map`:

```
"abc".map( c => c match {
  case 'a' => "a1"
  case 'b' => if(b) "b2" else ""
  case 'c' => "c3"
  case _ =>
}).mkString("")
```